# How similar is CentOS 6.6 to Rocks 6.2?

Tags: centos, distributions

Rocks is based off CentOS, the same way Mint is based off Ubuntu. Will all the programs that run on CentOS 6.6 run on Rocks 6.2 (sidewinder)? This is the case with Mint and Ubuntu, but with Rocks and CentOS, I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rocks **6.2** is called Sidewinder, and is based on CentOS 6.6.

Rocks **4.2** was called Hassalan, and was based on CentOS 4.3.

You will need to test to verify, but you should be able to run Rocks on any hardware on the HCL for RedHat/CentOS.  You should also be able to run any software intended for Centos 6.6 on Rocks 6.2, simply by adding the appropriate Yum Repositor(y|ies).

See the **Adding Other Packages** section of this page: http://ir.dcs.gla.ac.uk/wiki/CompBioCluster/ClusterAdministration